# GridView set header View height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, height, android-gridview

I'm implementing a GridView with a Header View ([GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter))
. I want that the HeaderView takes 1/3 of the screen height. The problem is that in the `header_view.xml` I have to set a `layout_height` value, otherwise the view is not visible.

Here is my Activity:

```
    public class TestGVHeader extends Activity  {

    Context context = this;

    private GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridView;
    private ProductsGridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_gvheader);

        gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_header_view, null);

        gridView.addHeaderView(headerView);

        gridViewAdapter = new ProductsGridViewAdapter(this, getProducts());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) headerView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new CataloguePagerAdapter(context, this, this.getCatalogues());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }
}
```

The activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<in.srain.cube.views.GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1sp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1sp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
</in.srain.cube.views.GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter>
```

and the header view layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Does anybody knows how to set the `android:layout_height="450dp"` to 1/3 of the screen height instead of a fixed value?
Thanks.

Comment: try `android:weight="0.65"`

Comment: do you mean `android:layout_weight="0.65"`? If I set `android:layout_weight="0.65"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` the `ViewPager` is not visible :(

Comment: set `android:layout_height="wrap_content" `and `android:layout_weight="0.06"`

Comment: not working. If I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or `android:layout_height="match_parent"` the `ViewPager` is not visible anymore, doesn't matter what I set in `android:layout_weight`

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do with the custom `ViewGroup` of the header view, in your case it's `FrameLayout`. You just have to override `onMeasure` method and calculate the height as 1/3 of your screen height. So, firstly, create the next custom view class in your project:

```
public class OneThreeScreenFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public OneThreeScreenFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public OneThreeScreenFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public OneThreeScreenFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        int oneThreeHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(screenHeight / 3,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, oneThreeHeight);
    }
}
```

And then use it as your `header_view` root. Note that we set its height to `0dp` as we will change it anyway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.name.OneThreeScreenFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</your.package.name.OneThreeScreenFrameLayout>
```

That's it! Your header view now is 1/3 of screen height. The example is below:

[image]

Comment: It look like It will work. In my case Main base is Fragment &  It's a LinearLayout which holds ViewPager & then I am adding this as headerView in GridLayout Using this GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter. Everything coming as expected but if we have more Items & we scroll Up and down Fast. Then It's Crashing on last line of onMeasure(). `super.onMeasure(widthSpec, oneThreeHeight);`

Comment: So if you have a `LinearLayout` as a root view of the header view then you need to create `OneThreeScreenLinearLayout extends LinearLayout` and make the same thing in `onMeasure` method. And then use it instead of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Ok. Let me Try IT. If it's working I'll be so much Happy.

Comment: Don't I need to Pass `oneThreeHeight` value anywhere?

Comment: You have to. The `onMeasure` method implementation will be the same

Comment: If it won't work, you can paste here your exception log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128350/discussion-between-greenrobo-and-rom4ek).